# Import file to node from ENV variable

Tags: node.js

I am trying to import json file from system, 
in script if i go with :

```
const creds = require('C:\\Users\\WTF\\creds.json');
```

then I can see the imported file, but when I try this with env variable as such:

```
 $env:LOCAL_ENV_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\WTF\creds.json" //powershell command to set to env
const creds = require(process.env.env:LOCAL_ENV_CREDENTIALS as string); //fetching code
```

then I get the error

```
"message": "Cannot find module 'C:\\Users\\WTF\\creds.json'",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd log your process.env in the node script to ensure it can see the variable.
Also it looks like the line should be changed to

```
const creds = require(process.env.LOCAL_ENV_CREDENTIALS);
```

Comment: I made another solution working, as said in comment up, If I were to do something like this const path = 'C:/Users ....' and then go with require(path), then it breaks, so I assume its something with TS transpiler setings

Comment: can you add your transpiler configuration?